# python over-writing my list elements

Tags: python, list, class

Fairly new to python, very new to python classes.  Question is a bit involved.  Most appreciative of your patience:

I have a class "Star".  It is simple.  Attributes x, v, and mass.  Another class, Galaxy, has an attribute "stars" which is just a list of star objects:

```
class Galaxy:

    numstars=0.
    stars=[]

    def __init__(self,numin,xes,vees,masses):
        self.numstars=numin
        for n in range(numin):
            self.stars.append(Star(xes[n],vees[n],masses[n]))
```

Galaxy also has an attribute function called time_stepper.  Suffice it to say time_stepper just updates all the elements of "stars" and then returns "stars":

```
def time_stepper(self,dt):
    self.velstep(dt)
    self.xstep(dt)
    self.velstep(dt)
    return(self.stars)
```

Now, I'm trying to drive this thing and store the various updates of "stars" in a list called "history":

```
gal=Galaxy(#stuff#)
history=[]
for n in range(100):
    history.append(gal.time_stepper(.1))
```

Finally, my question:  In each iteration of this loop, the new element of "stars" is added to "history", but ... and here it is ... *all the previous elements of history are over-written and given the same values as the newest element of history!*  So what is going on?  I've run into things about python lists that I didn't understand before, but I thought I finally had it nailed down.  Apparently not.  Thanks for your help.

Addendum:
Thanks to everyone for your help.  Didn't expect that many helpful replies and especially so soon.  My problem was that I was assuming these two pieces of code were essentially the same.  First:

```
>>> a=[]
>>> b=[1,2,3]
>>> a.append(b)
>>> b=[4,5,6]
>>> a.append(b)
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Second:

```
>>> a=[]
>>> b=[1,2,3]
>>> a.append(b)
>>> b[:]=(4,5,6)
>>> b
[4, 5, 6]
>>> a.append(b)
>>> a
[[4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]
```

And whoops!  They aren't.  So in code 1, I guess, b is "re-pointed" to a completely new memory location while a[0] continues to point the the old b.  In the second, the memory at b is "edited" and a[0] is still pointing to that location.  After the append, a[1] is also pointing to that location.  Do I have it now?

I'm very new to python and am still figuring out the "pythonic" philosophy.  But to me, having a reassignment of pointers done straightforwardly, but a "deep copy" done in a more complicated way is sort of backwards from the way I usually want to do things.  Can anyone enlighten me?  Thanks again.

Comment: Why are `numstars` and `stars` class variables instead of instance variables? (And, if you do have a good reason for that, why immediately replace the class `numstars` with an instance `numstars` in the `__init__` function?)

Comment: Without seeing the code for the update function in `Star`, it's hard for me to recommend anything other than [`copy.deepcopy`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)

Comment: Bob, you got a syntax error in that last line of code.

Comment: @abarnet: The answer to your question is that I have no idea what I am doing! :)

Comment: @ inspectorG4dget:  copy.deepcopy is apparently what I needed.  Thanks.

Comment: @MikeHunter: Fixed it.  That wasn't in the original code.  Just left out a character in my copy and paste.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is worth noting that if you have more than 1 galaxy, they'll share the same stars.  This could lead you to believe that you're overwriting your stars when you really aren't...

I'm guessing you would probably be better with an `__init__` that looks like:

```
def __init__(self,numin,xes,vees,masses):
    self.stars = []
    self.numstars = numin
    for n in range(numin):
        self.stars.append(Star(xes[n],vees[n],masses[n]))
```

Here I've shifted the *class attribute* `stars` to be an *instance attribute*.  Now each instance will have it's own `stars` list instead of sharing one `stars` list with all of the other galaxies in the universe.

As others have noted, your `history` list is going to suffer from a similar problem (You have multiple references to *the same list*).  However, the fix really depends on what you do in `self.velstep` and `self.xstep`.  If you modify the `Star` objects in place, then a simple (shallow) list copy won't do you any good (e.g. `gal.time_stepper(0.1)[:]`).  (You'll create a new list, but it will hold the same stars which are constantly being updated).  In that case, you'll want `copy.deepcopy` when you append to your history list:

```
history=[]
for n in range(100):
    history.append(copy.deepcopy(gal.time_stepper(.1)))
```

Comment: This is all good… but it doesn't actually solve the OP's problem. He still needs to do `history.append(gal.time_stepper(.1))[:]`, or some equivalent way of getting a distinct object.

Comment: @abarnert -- Yeah, I realized that, however I don't even think making a shallow copy will do it.  I'm guessing, but I would bet that OP needs a `copy.deepcopy` because my money says the `Star` objects get modified in place.

Comment: You may want to run this through a spell-checker… both "galexy" and "mality" jump out at me even from a quick list. But otherwise, all good.

Comment: @arbarnert: Yep.  `copy.deepcopy` is what did the trick.  Star is modified in place.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is because the `stars` list is mutable - it is a changeable variable. When you call `stars.append`, it does not create a new list - it simple edits the existing list. And when you call `history.append(x)`, python does not create a fresh, clean copy of `x` - it assumes you want the "real" `x` to be placed in the `history` array.

If you'd like to copy the state of the list at each iteration, there are several options (see [How to clone a list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-a-list-in-python)).

The [`copy` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) will do the trick. It offers both 'shallow' and 'deep' copies - roughly speaking, deep copies attempt to also copy any other variables they find inside an object (for example, lists containing other lists), while shallow ones just go one layer down:

Here's shallow copies with `copy`:

```
import copy

history=[]
for n in range(100):
    history.append(copy.copy(gal.time_stepper(.1)))
```

And deep copies:

```
import copy

history=[]
for n in range(100):
    history.append(copy.deepcopy(gal.time_stepper(.1)))
```

Slicing the array will work, since it always shallow copies as an intermediate step:

```
history = []
for n in range(100):
    history.append(gal.time_stepper(.1)[:])
```

You can also call `list` on the existing list - this typecast-esque operation always returns a new list object (again, shallowly):

```
history = []
for n in range(100):
    history.append(list(gal.time_stepper(.1)))
```

Comment: Why use `copy.copy` instead of just `[:]`?

Comment: @abarnert Readability. `[:]` falls into the 'neat python tricks' category, to me.

Comment: It's a standard idiom, and it's used in both the tutorial section and the official FAQ answer that talk about this issue, so avoiding it is being unpythonic.

Comment: However, introducing `copy.copy` in the answer hints at the `copy` module and the subsequent `copy.deepcopy`, which might be helpful to the OP in the future.

Comment: @abarnert I suppose I disagree with the usage in those docs, then. I'm with Alex Martelli when he says "it is a weird syntax and it does not make sense to use it ever." (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-a-list-in-python)

Comment: @abarnert I'll edit the post to mention that there are many ways of copying a list.

Answer (score 1):

It is not changing or over writing all of the values, but rather all of the elements in the history point to the same array object.  You need to assign by value as opposed to reference by using a copy of the array.