# Python, object gets the values of the new one

Tags: python, oop

I have the following code:

```
import math

class h:
    vektor = [0,0]
    rel_chyba = 0

    def __init__(self, hodnota, chyba):
        self.vektor[0] = hodnota
        self.vektor[1] = chyba
        self.rel_chyba = chyba*1.0/hodnota

    def __rmul__(self, hod2):
        return h(hod2.vektor[0]*self.vektor[0],  math.sqrt(self.rel_chyba*self.rel_chyba+hod2.rel_chyba*hod2.rel_chyba))

v = h(12,1)
print v.vektor[1]
t = h(25,2)
print v.vektor[1]
```

My problem is, that v.vektor[1] prints 1 for the first time and 2 for the second time. All the attributes of the object v are assigned the values of the attributes from t.

How can I create two different objects?
Thanks for your answers

Comment: and also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13482727/748858

Comment: Also please don't call it `class h:`. That's horrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't declare `vektor` at class level, that makes it a class variable. Just declare it inside `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, hodnota, chyba):
    self.vektor = [hodnota, chyba]
```

Comment: Also see http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

Comment: thanks, i had to add self.vektor = [0,0] in the constructor, but it works fine now